# QGIS server 3 failed on debian 9

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, debian

I have install on a Debian 9 a qgis-server, python-qgis, apache2 and libapache2-mod-fcgid. Apache service is runnning.

I have a folder uder `usr/lib/cgi-bin/` but when I request `http://localhost//cgi-bin/test/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&MAP=projet_test.qgs`

I have edited the conf file to enable fcgi.

Everything works on qgis-server 2.14 but not on qgis-server 3.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "QGIS server 3 failed"?

To locate the origin of your problem, you should active error logs on different levels and post the outputs like:

- Apache error logs
- PostgreSQL error logs, in case your QGIS project uses layers from database
- QGIS Server debug log following [the docs](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/plugins.html#http-server-configuration)

I remember a problem I had when migrating to QGIS Server 3 which was related to a missing PATH variable described in [this issue](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18230).

To solve this issue on Debian and Ubuntu I had to add add the following lines to */etc/apache2/sites-available/qgis-server.conf*:

```
# FIX path to library see https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18230
FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_PREFIX_PATH "/usr"
SetEnv QGIS_PREFIX_PATH "/usr"
```